# Reference request: Elliptic regularity estimate in domains with $C^{1,\alpha}$ boundary

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, sobolev-spaces

I'm wondering if there is a reference for the following (or if it's not true). Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain with $C^{1,\alpha}$ boundary, where $0<\alpha<1$. For the inhomogeneous Dirichlet problem,
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\Delta u&=f,\hspace{5mm}\text{on}\hspace{2mm}\Omega
\\
u_{|\partial\Omega}&=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
do we have an estimate of the form
\begin{equation}
\|u\|_{H^{s}}\leq C\|f\|_{H^{s-2}}
\end{equation}
for the range $1\leq s<\frac{3}{2}+\alpha$ (maybe perhaps even including the endpoint $s=\frac{3}{2}+\alpha$?). There seems to have been much work done in the case of a Lipschitz domain (but necessarily with a more restrictive range for $s$ requiring $s<\frac{3}{2}$). I'm actually mostly interested in the case where $\alpha$ is close to zero (so, the domain is a bit more regular than $C^1$).